# Snell's law demonstration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometry, fiber-optics

I'm a bit confused about a Snell's law demonstration.

I'm reading Communication Systems from W. Tomasi.

In the chapter 11, the author applies the Snell's law to θent, and -here comes my problem- he says that **θ1 (the refraction angle) is equal to 90 - θc (the critical angle)**. How can be this possible? The critical angle is a constant just like 90°, and the refraction angle varies in function of θent (the incidence angle).

So, my question is: Is this an error book (I saw a lot of errors) or maybe am I forgetting something (I mean, a mathematical property or some concept)?

Thanks.

[image]
[image: Optical fibre diagram]

Comment: I suspect he's "working backwards," so once you've forced the setup to have $\theta_c$ at B, then $\theta_1$ must be the complementary angle due to obvious geometry.  Then you use Snell's law to calculate the exterior angle $\theta_ent$ .  What he's deriving is the maximum possible entrance angle to get propagation down the fiber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not an error, because the diagram looks at the *maximum* angle specifically (and that's where the equality holds). He is saying that inside an optical fiber, there is a ray that travels at the critical angle: this ray, when it comes out of the fiber, represents the maximum possible exit angle.

As the refractive index mismatch between the fiber and the cladding changes, so does the critical angle - and with it, the maximum exit angle. Note this is also the maximum acceptance angle, so illuminating a fiber for which the critical angle is very glancing (small refractive index mismatch) with an uncollimated source will lead to very poor transmission (only a very small fraction of light will enter the fiber).

Read about the concept of "Numerical Aperture" (NA) of fibers.

Comment: pfffffft.... so much for my comment :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - we were writing the same thing, basically. Why didn't you just write it as an answer? Because that's what it is...

Comment: Oh! Thanks to both... And, by the way, @CarlWitthoft your explanation was very insightful, I mean, I didn't see the obvious triangle that now I see.

Comment: Floris, just because I'm lazy :-) .  Your answer is fine.